# Category page take too much time to load because of search_tmp_* table

Tags: magento2, search, query, category-listing

my sites category page slows down because firing query for search_tmp_* table take more than 1 second and it runs saveral time on one page load here is the query :

### 7624 ## QUERY

SQL: INSERT INTO `search_tmp_5ce2b13088d284_52718722` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  `eav_index`.`entity_id`, (((0) + (0)) * 1 + SUM(CASE WHEN cea.search_weight > 1 THEN((CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE ' bazookagoal ' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END+CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '% bazookagoal %' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END+CASE WHEN `data_index` LIKE '%bazookagoal%' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END+CASE WHEN 11 * ((11 / LENGTH(data_index)) + (1/(LENGTH(data_index) - ( LENGTH(data_index) 
                    - LOCATE("bazookagoal",data_index))))) THEN 11 * ((11 / LENGTH(data_index)) + (1/(LENGTH(data_index) - ( LENGTH(data_index) 
                    - LOCATE("bazookagoal",data_index))))) ELSE 0 END)) ELSE 0 END * POW(2, cea.search_weight))) AS score FROM `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `eav_index`
 INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` AS `search_index` ON eav_index.entity_id = search_index.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `cea` ON search_index.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_index` ON stock_index.product_id = eav_index.entity_id AND `stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `stock_index`.`stock_status` = 1 AND `stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `category_ids_index` ON eav_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id AND category_ids_index.store_id = '1' WHERE (eav_index.store_id = '1') AND (`eav_index`.`attribute_id` = 99 AND `eav_index`.`value` in ('3', '4') AND `eav_index`.`store_id` = '1') AND (category_ids_index.category_id = 2) GROUP BY `entity_id` HAVING ((((GROUP_CONCAT(data_index) LIKE '%bazookagoal%'))))) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `entity_id` DESC
 LIMIT 100000
AFF: 1
TIME: 1.5136

Please Help

Comment: This is Bug of Magento 2.Tmp table create the issue. Suggest to upgrade the Magento system  2.3 and use Elastic search

Comment: @AmitBera Thank you for your response. you are right but is there any way to resolve this issue in current Magento 2 version

Comment: current Magento 2 version is 2.2.6